# Local downlevel document

Tags: windows

I am using a desktop application that will monitor the spooler and show print jobs. This application uses FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification() and FindNextPrinterChangeNotification() with PRINTER_CHANGE_ADD_JOB to monitor job added to printer. When a job is added, I use EnumJobs to get the job name and status. I am getting the name as Local Downlevel Document from EnumJobs although the job gets printed properly and spooler also shows the job name correctly. I tried to give some delay before calling EnumJobs, but in that case the job gets spooled out and nothing gets returned. Please tell me how I can get the jobname correctly.

The behavior is same in Windows 8.1 and Windows 10.